# Makeshift way to drain a battery?

Tags: led, batteries, battery-charging, discharge, mobile

I have a 3.8V mobile-phone battery that I need to discharge.
However I don't have any electrical components (*say led*) with me.

What is a crude way to do this using household items?

Comment: Make a resistor out of a pencil. Wire it across the battery.

Comment: Does it matter if the battery explodes or is otherwise rendered permanently inoperable?

Comment: Salty water in a small glass and a couple of bare wires (aka paper clips)

Comment: would definitely not want it to explode.

Comment: @JImDearden You'll be generating sodium hydroxide, chlorine and hydrogen doing that. After further reactions, unless you keep the sodium hydroxide and chlorine apart, you end up with hydrogen and household bleach (sodium chlorate). Could be nasty.

Comment: @Majenko  I know it will generate hydrogen and sodium hypochlorite (NaOCl aka bleach), I did do chemistry, but the question invites **CRUDE** ways using household items.

Comment: @JImDearden Ah, but is that *crude* as in *primitive*, or *crude* as in *nudge nudge, wink wink, say no more, squire*?

Comment: @Majenko lol - I see you took the constipated mathematician's solution and worked it out with a pencil.

Comment: @JImDearden A pencil? It took a *log table* to work mine out ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "lead" of a modern pencil is made of Graphite.  Graphite is a form of Carbon. Carbon is what they make some resistors out of.

Your typical HB pencil has a resistance of around 150Ω-200Ω (I just measured the one on my desk - 172Ω).

Strip the wood from both ends of the pencil and wire it to the terminals of the battery.

$$
I=\frac{V}{R} = \frac{3.8}{172} = 22mA
$$

A 2000mAh battery would be flat in about 4 days.

To discharge faster, break the pencil in half or wire multiple pencils in parallel.

Note that drawing too much current through a single short pencil may get so hot it sets the wood of the pencil on fire.

Comment: @Ashesh - I'm assuming this is a lithium-based battery.  Don't discharge it all the way!  The minimum is usually considered 2.7 - 3.0V.  Any lower can cause the battery to fail. And failed lithium batteries can explode :)

Comment: I was just curious ;-).